# How can I added to link attribute preload in webpack 4 (for chunks or min)?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have some problem with understanding how can I add a rule (or rules) for webpack plugin MiniCssExtractPlugin about attribute preload for link

example :

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: 'frontassets/css/[name].[hash:10].css',
  chunkFilename: 'frontassets/css/[id].[chunkhash:10].css',
}),
```

or I needed to use another plugin for attribute preload link?

My case:
I need add preload for CSS chunks for needed URLs which using CSS chunks

Comment: preload attribute for link you can add only in html

Comment: So, webpack cannot help me? We use React and Webpack of course.

Comment: you can try require file from html template

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader

Comment: ok I will try, thanks

Comment: Webpack does not help you on that. The preload is done while adding the css into the page. You can try to do that with html-webpack-plugin too